# Python: json data write to a file str

Tags: python, json, string, twitter

---

Hi! Here is code:

```
def on_data(self, data):
    j_data = json.loads(data)
    tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
    print j_data[u"text"]


    saveTweet = str(time.time())+'::'+tweet
    saveFile = open('tweetDB1.csv','a')
    saveFile.write(saveTweet)
    saveFile.write('\n')
    saveFile.close()
```

BUT! I need to write a tweet in file as a string without any garbarge there. If i write print tweet (not print j_data[u"text"]) I'll have utf-8 code, not encode:
-\u0422\u044b \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043b

How can I fix it?

Comment: That's not garbage.. That is just an encoding. What's the data like?

Comment: Also tried to tweet = j_data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0] , but i have an error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: data is like:
о лето, пора загорать и спортом заниматься.
А верится с трудом...
Турчинов заявил об уничтожении укреплений ополченцев близ Славянска и Краматорска - Интерфакс http://t.co/7eL5mUOdwY
BUT when it write to a file - it write like thousand symbols \u0422\u044b \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043b

Comment: You have something like `Ты видел`? Also, which python version are you  using?

Comment: Yes. But when i write into a file - it is "\u0438\u0434\u" , not "Ты видел? "
Python 2.7

Comment: Why not write JSON to your file instead? And why load your JSON into `j_data`, then **ignore the result**? You are manipulating the original JSON data string.

Comment: I don't know how to write j_data into a file as a string

Comment: @user3584920: encode the Unicode value to an encoding of your choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append just the text field to a CSV file, use:

```
def on_data(self, data):
    j_data = json.loads(data)
    tweet = j_data[u"text"]

    with open('tweetDB1.csv', 'a') as save_file:
        save_file.write('{}::{}\n'.format(time.time(), tweet.encode('utf8'))
```

This loads the original JSON data into a dictionary, uses *just* the `text` field, and encodes it to UTF-8 when writing to the file.

Your version used the JSON-encoded string, ignoring the `j_data` dictionary altogether. You could just as well have removed the `json.loads()` call. JSON uses `\u....` escape sequences to represent Unicode codepoints. The above writes UTF-8 data instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should encode your data.

`saveTweet=saveTweet.encode(encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: what is your json data?
please give me a example. Thank you.

Comment: data is like:
А верится с трудом... Турчинов заявил об уничтожении укреплений ополченцев близ Славянска и Краматорска - Интерфакс

Comment: you should try add 
`# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-`
in the python file head.

Comment: pls, look at comments under my question

Comment: Sorry,I test the data. like this [link](http://codepad.org/iEQNnLjN)
And it's no problem. So what is your saveTweet data?

Comment: in shell window when i stats my script i see a normal data (Турчинов заявил об уничтожении укреплений ополченцев близ Славянска и Краматорск and etc.), but when it writes to a file data looks like \u0422\u044b \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043b

Comment: you can try test your saveTweet data type 
`type(saveTweet)` if is type 'unicode'
you should `saveTweet.encode(encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: no no, i need to write a data in strings (j_data), but i write a tweet and file is empty at all . How do i change  `saveTweet = str(time.time())+'::'+tweet` to a `j_data`??

Comment: I have a little don't understand your meaning...Sorry